# How do I change the appearance of the window that has focus?

Tags: macos, window-manager

I find that I frequently close the wrong window or app by accident, because I think that (for example) the Browser window I am looking at has the focus, when in fact another app, such as iTerm really has focus.  (It doesn't help that I am able to scroll windows that don't have focus.)

When I look at the visual appearance of windows, the difference between the one that has focus and the ones that don't is very slight: the focused window has a slightly different shade of gray in the title bar, and the three round buttons at the upper-left are red, yellow, and green instead of gray.

If the title bar was some completely different, non-gray color it would stand out more.  I tried going to System Preferences:General, but changing the "Highlight color" doesn't affect the window's title bar. I couldn't find anything else under System Preferences that seemed relevant.

How can I change the appearance of the focused window so it stands out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a software that can visually highlight focused windows more?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89743/is-there-a-software-that-can-visually-highlight-focused-windows-more)

Comment: @klanomath this seems to imply that the answer to my question is, "You can't without buying 3rd party software" ... :(

Comment: Please check the 2nd answer: [Honer](https://github.com/puffnfresh/Honer.app) seems to be free!

Comment: @klanomath i saw that, but it requires mavericks and i am running mountain lion (per the tag)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check your tags properly.

Comment: You may try to compile Honer for ML with an older Xcode or ask the author what changes in the source code are needed to adapt it to ML

Comment: @klanomath I was hoping there would be a simple fix... cost/benefit wise anything beyond a simple (hidden?) config option seems hardly worth it to avoid closing the wrong window a couple times a day.

Comment: How are you closing the windows? Command W or mouse or other situation? I find using full screen mode reduces the mental strain of picking which window to focus on. Also a big fan the new split screen UI but that's not ML

Comment: @bmike I'm using Command+W.  Full screen won't work for me because (1) i usually have at least 3 windows with info I need visible at once, and (2) i've got a lot of screen space across two devices: 27" iMac and a 21"  second display.

Comment: Got it - you're right that three doesn't work - but if you were to edit that into the question, people might offer suggestions like Divvy to automate window opening / closing / positioning. Cheers and hopefully will have a better suggestion than my only one which would sum up as "learn different habits" : (

Comment: Isn’t an issue in Windows [which has a setting to fix the bad default behavior](https://imgur.com/a/lpq3izD). Is there really no equivalent in Mac OS X?